# IIS windows authentication works for website but not for web application under website

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have a website hosted in IIS using windows authentication. It works fine.
But if I host it as a web application unter a website, windows authentication doesn't work and the authentication window shows and then doesn't go away even if I put in the correct user name and password.
The SPN, delegation and IIS settings should be correct, otherwise the website won't work. Only if I deploy it as web application, windows authentication stoped working. Any idea?

Comment: What's the substatus code in IIS log files when the web browser prompts? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Besides, ask your domain administrators to help.

Comment: I got status code 401 because authentication failed

Comment: could you please share your iis application web.config file. I suggest you make sure the windows authentication is properly configured at the application level. check the iis log for the sub status code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution.
After enabling ASP.Net Impersonation on the web application, it works.
Seems like, the web application needs impersonation to get the kerberos ticket from the website.

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, the sub status code is 401.1 and here the web.config file on the application level

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\DataService.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```